# Why can't I use onsubmit to change innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, innerhtml

I need to use form fields in an English/Amino Acid Code translater. The code below is simplified to show the problem I'm having. I want to change some text with a javascript function.

If I use an input of type: *button* with *onclick* it works.

A *submit* button with *onsubmit* in a form changes the text for a split second, then it changes back. I need to use a form for my translation program so how can I make it work?

*Extra Credit: Why does it change for a split second with onsubmit?*

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeTo(text){
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML=text;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Change text in an element</h1>
<!--
<form onsubmit="changeTo('Hello World');">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
-->
<input type="button" onclick="changeTo('Hello World');" />
<p id="p1">text</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's changing it back because the form is submitting.  It posts to the same page, and if you are on a local machine it might be so quick you don't notice.  Try:

```
<form onsubmit="changeTo('Hello World');return false;">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Return false at the end there will stop the submission process.